# filepond-plugin-image-size-metadata configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, metadata, multer, filepond

I hope you're well, just wondering if anyone has successfully set up the filepond image size metadata plugin.

https://github.com/yoldar/filepond-plugin-image-size-metadata

The documentation, is somewhat lacking, currently I have set allowImageSizeMetadata as a parameter of the FilePond component:

```
<FilePond
name={file}
files={file}
allowMultiple={false}
allowImageSizeMetadata={true}
server={null}                
instantUpload={false}
onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => onFileChange(fileItems)}
/>
```

I have imported at the top of the file as so:

```
import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from 'react-filepond';

import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css';

import FilePondPluginImageSizeMetaData from 'filepond-plugin-image-size-metadata';
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from 'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation';
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';
import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css';
```

But when i log out the output in the console i'm not seeing anything extra, which I assume I should be like the width and height metadata.

Can anyone see something I might be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register it.

See for example the code snippet in the [image preview plugin docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-preview/).

```js
import * as FilePond from 'filepond';
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';
import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css';

// Register the plugin <- this call
FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);
```

Comment: All the plugins i'm using are registered, sorry missed that line off when posting question, so its not that.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know then, this is a third-party plugin, it seems to make use of the image orientation info, so make sure you register the image orientation plugin first. Maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: @old_blueyes The plugin is working, I am logging the metadata in process function of server object https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#process-1